# UISwipeGestureRecognizer ending point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have dynamically created some image views. By using UISwipeGestureRecognizer, I am able to get the starting point or tag of the image view from where swipe starts but I am not able to get the its ending tag or point.

Please help

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded methods to find the start/end positions of the swipe.

Use following method that may help you...

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     UITouch *touchendpoint = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint gestureEndPoint = [touchendpoint locationInView:self.view];
 }
```

Hope, this will help you..